# Validation Error Message before submitting app to App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, ios11, appstore-approval

I got following two error messages after successfully Archive and then validating the app.

### App Store Connect Operation Error Missing Info.plist value. A value for the Info.plist key 'CFBundleIconName' is missing in the bundle 'com.CompanyName.ProjectName’. Apps built with iOS 11 or later SDK must supply app icons in an asset catalog and must also provide a value for this Info.plist key. For more information see http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev10510b1f7.

### App Store Connect Operation Error Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 10.0.

[image]

Comment: Check the info.plist that's named in your target's build settings.  Does that info.plist specify the correct value for CFBundleIconName?  Show us. And show us the assets and appIcons within it.

Comment: you have to add your app icon (1024x1024) in the asset catalogue. second one, app misses the 120 px app icon. add that too in your asset catalogue.